# Bootstrap - starting a new column where the ther one ends

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a responsive column-based blocks(as "panel" in bootstrap) in my website.
My goal is to make the different-heighted blocks(panels) start when the other block ends - while there are 2 blocks at the same time in a full screen view.

Because they don't have the same height, When the first block ends - there are big blanked space to the bottom of the second block - and only after the second block ends, the 3rd block starts.

The images below will describe what I'm trying to say.

**Image 1** - 1st block and 2nd block are starting from the same line

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b0WR.png

**Image 2** - The first block ended, the second block didn't - and the 3rd block is not below the first block when he ends. The 3rd block apperas only when the 2nd block ends, which is in different column.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/76HXF.png

I want the 3rd block to start after the first one ends - without the big empty blanked space in the left of the 2nd block.

How I can do it?

All my cols are **col-md-6**.

Comment: If you want to have a two column layout on every screen size, so from `xs` onwards` create two columns and put every odd panel in the first column and every even panel in the second column. But please add some of your html and css explaining the problem to the question.

Comment: Don't you want to use 2 columns like this.. http://www.bootply.com/2F30H82A5e

Answer (score 0):

You can equalise the heights of the two divs using javascript and jQuery.
So if you have #div1 and #div2...

```js
$.fn.equaliseHeights = function() {
 return this.height(Math.max.apply(this, $(this).map(function(i, e) {
  return $(e).height();
 }).get()));
}
$("#div1").add($("#div2")).equaliseHeights();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```